# liquibase is read-only : liquibase is locked and cannot unlock it (pod on openshift)

Tags: spring, postgresql, openshift, liquibase

I'm using JHispter to generate my app based on a React front and a Spring backend. I have created a docker image and pushed it to my OpenShift project.

In my local machine, all is OK, but when the pod is created on OpenShift, I get this error when it's started:

> Liquibase could not start correctly, your database is NOT ready: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL UPDATE PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET LOCKED = TRUE, LOCKEDBY = '-745467d44f-84gzt (10.128.42.54)', LOCKGRANTED = '2020-06-30 19:02:03.817' WHERE ID = 1 AND LOCKED = FALSE: The database is read only; SQL statement: UPDATE PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET LOCKED = TRUE, LOCKEDBY = '-745467d44f-84gzt (10.128.42.54)', LOCKGRANTED = '2020-06-30 19:02:03.806' WHERE ID = 1 AND LOCKED = FALSE [90097-200]

Thanks in advance for your help,
kr

Answer (score 0):

Apparently a previous Liquibase run didn't finish cleanly and thus the locked flag wasn't reset.

If you are certain that no concurrent scripts are running, just reset the flag in the database:

```
update databasechangeloglock
   set locked = false, lockedby = null, lockgranted = null;
```